# Assembly memory operands clarification

Tags: assembly, x86

I understand when for example [BX] is in between brackets it is referring to its memory contents. But at the same time I do not understand that.

```
CMP [BX], 12ADH
```

In that example I do not understand what is really being compared.

```
MOV EBX, [BX]
```

Same for this move, I don't get what is being moved its memory address or the value inside of it.

Comment: Both of those use memory as you said. The first compares the word at address `bx` to `12ADh`, the second fetches the dword from address `bx` (this form is unusual, although legal).

Comment: If BX=10, then [BX] refer to memory at address 10. If this is clear, what is not? Which one is source and which is destination depends on assembler syntax (Intel ant AT&T these are oposite). In Your case it seems to be Intel, so first operand is destination.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that this is 16-bit assembly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CMP [BX], 12ADH
```

This is actually an invalid instruction, as you haven't specified the size of the first operand.  Assuming you intend a WORD (16-bit) comparison, like:

```
CMP WORD [BX], 12ADH
```

This will first fetch a 16-bit WORD from memory at the address specified in the BX register. Then, it will compare that value to the immediate value `12ADh`.

Note that `CMP` does the same thing as `SUB`, but without actually modifying any values. It only "pretends" to do the subtraction, and sets the `FLAGS` accordingly.

---

```
MOV EBX, [BX]
```

This will fetch a 32-bit DWORD from memory at the address specified in the BX register. Then, it will store that value in the EBX register.

---

In an expression like `WORD [BX]`, we can say that BX "points to" a 16-bit WORD in memory:

```
         Memory             Register File
           ...
        _________             ________
 100h  |  1234h  |     /---- |  102h  | BX
       |_________|     |     |________|
 102h  |  5678h  | <---/        ...
       |_________|
 104h  |  9ABCh  |
       |_________|
 106h  |  DEF0h  |
       |_________|
           ...
```